# django - markdown and codehilite

Tags: django, markdown

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong, but I can't get codehilite to generate code properly, example:

```
from markdown import markdown
self.content_html = markdown(self.content, ['codehilite'])
```

and I'm using this C# from wikipedia to test

```
public class GenericList<T>
{
    void Add(T input) { }
}

class TestGenericList
{
    private class ExampleClass { }
    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare a list of type int.
        GenericList<int> list1 = new GenericList<int>();

        // Declare a list of type string.
        GenericList<string> list2 = new GenericList<string>();

        // Declare a list of type ExampleClass.
        GenericList<ExampleClass> list3 = new GenericList<ExampleClass>();
    }
}
```

and the result is

```
<p>public class GenericList<T>
{
    void Add(T input) { }
}</p>
<p>class TestGenericList
{
    private class ExampleClass { }
    static void Main()
    {
        // Declare a list of type int.
        GenericList<int> list1 = new GenericList<int>();</p>
<div class="codehilite"><pre>    <span class="c1">// Declare a list of type string.</span>
    <span class="nx">GenericList</span><span class="o">&lt;</span><span class="kt">string</span><span class="o">&gt;</span> <span class="n">list2</span> <span class="o">=</span> <span class="nb">new</span> <span class="nx">GenericList</span><span class="o">&lt;</span><span class="kt">string</span><span class="o">&gt;</span><span class="p">();</span>

    <span class="c1">// Declare a list of type ExampleClass.</span>
    <span class="nx">GenericList</span><span class="o">&lt;</span><span class="nx">ExampleClass</span><span class="o">&gt;</span> <span class="n">list3</span> <span class="o">=</span> <span class="nb">new</span> <span class="nx">GenericList</span><span class="o">&lt;</span><span class="nx">ExampleClass</span><span class="o">&gt;</span><span class="p">();</span>
<span class="p">}</span>
</pre></div>


<p>}</p>
```

As you can see, it didn't mark first few lines, and then started with comment  `// Declare a list of type string.` What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you should use [pygments](http://pygments.org/).

then try putting a `:::<language>` block up in your markdown before the block of code [so it knows how to interpret it](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/code_hilite.html#colons).

I wrote a article series about [using markdown pygments to create a django blog](http://www.yaconiello.com/blog/part-1-creating-blog-system-using-django-markdown/) that may be helpfull as well.

### EDIT (this is whats up i think)

you need 4 spaces preceding each line of code for codehilite to pick up on it. ALSO, the first and last lines of code need a `\n` before and after, your code cannot be butted up against regular text (not indented by 4 spaces). ALSO, your code cannot be embedded into a bulleted list